# Javascript if statement not executing 2nd parameter

Tags: javascript, redirect, if-statement

I have a var that is either 1 or 0, if it's 1 the page should go to cnn.com if it's 0 it should go to google.com. Problem is, when it's 1 or 0 it always goes to google.com. Check out the running version at http://jsbin.com/ucovef/7   Thanks in advance

```
function random(){
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
document.getElementById('randomnumber').innerHTML=(randomnumber);
check_random()
}
function check_random(){
if (randomnumber = 0){
this.location.href ="http://www.cnn.com";
}
if (randomnumber = 1){
this.location.href="http://www.google.com";
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need:

```
if (randomnumber == 0)
```

And:

```
if (randomnumber == 1)
```

Expressions `randomnumber = 0` and `randomnumber = 1` are **assignment expressions** that assign numbers `0` and `1` to the variables, despite them being inside an `if` conditional statement.

So, it always goes to **google.com** because everything not equal to `0` is a `true` expression in **JavaScript**.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use == to make a check. = sets the value instead of evaluating it. I would also suggest passing the random number to the function.

```
function random(){
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
    document.getElementById('random').innerHTML=(randomnumber);
    check_random(randomnumber)
}

function check_random(randomnumber){
    if (randomnumber == 0){
        this.location.href ="http://www.cnn.com";
    }
    else if(randomnumber == 1){
        this.location.href="http://www.google.com";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Don't use an id with the same name as the variable. Rename the id of the div to "random" and pass the randomnumber to the script like I describe above. It works fine then. http://jsbin.com/ucovef/18

Answer (score 1):

You must use == not = !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ben, you are using local variable from `random` in `check_random`. This won't work. Try this

```
function random(){
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
document.getElementById('randomnumber').innerHTML=(randomnumber);
check_random(randomnumber)
}
function check_random(n){
if (n == 0){
this.location.href ="http://www.cnn.com";
}
if (n == 1){
this.location.href="http://www.google.com";
}
}
```